# Find and change password using single linux pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
MESSLY:
  mail address: ubuntu://basics:password@host:1521/oracle
  directory_name: common setup
  directory: /u11/dodge
  mail_server: mailnetwork
  my_homedir: /home/lucifer
  logic_path:
  error_path:
  mail_id:
     - xxxyyy@mail.com
```

Above is my config file. I am trying to change the password in this config file through shell script.
The cmd I'm using is

```
cat file_name.txt | grep "my_homedir" | grep -v "#" | awk '{FS=":";print $2}' |grep -B4 -w "$my_homedir" file_name.txt  | grep -o -P '(?<=//).*(?=@)' | cut -d ":" -f2
```

The following cmd will give output as `**password**`.
Now I need to change the password to another password In the same pipe.

Could someone please guide me?

expected output :

```
MESSLY:
  mail address: ubuntu://basics:new_passwd@host:1521/oracle
  directory_name: common setup
  directory: /u11/dodge
  mail_server: mailnetwork
  my_homedir: /home/lucifer
  logic_path:
  error_path:
  mail_id:
     - xxxyyy@mail.com
```

Comment: @anubhava Added the expected output

Comment: ok but why is your grep looking for `my_homedir`?

Comment: Ok . Similar to this config I have more config in the same file. So to change the password for all the config I am using a while loop. where in single loop it greps for `my_homedir` and goes 4 lines up , cut the username and password . Upto this stage I figured out but I need help in changing the password in the same pipeline

Comment: @Ajithkumar, Ok then its better to post sample which is capturing that case too, so that we could test it.

Comment: I suggest using `yq` for editing `yaml` files

Comment: @Ajithkumar, as per anubhava sir said `yq` should be considered as an option. Do you have `yq` installed on your system? Or you could install it in case its not there?

Comment: @Ajithkumar, Hi Ajith(superstar :) ) could you please do let us know how these solutions went for you?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only. Where OP has mentioned that there could be multiple sections of `MESSLY` and only those sections should be edited which have `my_homedir` in it. Using `tac` + `awk` combinations here. As per experts advise tools like `yq` should be used, if OP doesn't have capability to install it then this could be used but it can't be guaranteed to work tools like `yq`, this is written as per shown samples only.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk -v newPass="new_passwd" '
/^MESSLY/   { found="" }
/my_homedir/{ found=1  }
found && /mail address:/{
   match($0,/.*:\/\/[^:]*:/)
   first=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
   last=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
   sub(/.*@/,newPass"@",last)
   print first last
   first=last=""
   next
}
1' | 
tac
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have this input:

```sh
cat file.yml

MESSLY:
  mail address: ubuntu://basics:passwd@host:1521/oracle
  directory_name: common setup
  directory: /u11/dodge
  mail_server: mailnetwork
  my_homedir: /home/lucifer
  logic_path:
  error_path:
  mail_id:
     - xxxyyy@mail.com

MESSLY:
  mail address: ubuntu://basics:passwd@host:1521/oracle
  directory_name: common setup
  directory: /u11/dodge
  mail_server: mailnetwork
  my_homedir: /home/abcd
  logic_path:
  error_path:
  mail_id:
     - xxxyyy@mail.com
```

You may then use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v RS= -v d='/home/lucifer' -v pass='new_password' '
$0 ~ d && match($0, /[[:space:]]mail address:[^\n]+/) {
   $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) \
   gensub(/^(([^:]*:){3})[^@]+(@.*)/, "\\1" pass "\\2", "1", substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)) \
   substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
{
   ORS=RT
} 1' file.yml
```

```sh
MESSLY:
  mail address: ubuntu://basics:new_password//basics:
  directory_name: common setup
  directory: /u11/dodge
  mail_server: mailnetwork
  my_homedir: /home/lucifer
  logic_path:
  error_path:
  mail_id:
     - xxxyyy@mail.com

MESSLY:
  mail address: ubuntu://basics:passwd@host:1521/oracle
  directory_name: common setup
  directory: /u11/dodge
  mail_server: mailnetwork
  my_homedir: /home/abcd
  logic_path:
  error_path:
  mail_id:
     - xxxyyy@mail.com
```

However do consider using `yq` for manipulating `yaml` files.